# typescript: need to provide class _methods_ for class instantiation?

Tags: class, typescript, methods, properties, arguments

I have declared a class Month in my typescript project. It has 6 properties and 7 member methods, 4 of which are private.

When trying to instantiate an instance of Month via the following code, I'm getting an error saying that I didn't provide a method as argument to the parameter. this.hasAdditionalCategories is class method. Why do I need to provide it? My understanding was that I need to provide the properties only to instantiate, and then the instance would inherit the methods from the class definition.

Does this seem plausible? Cheers

The error message is

[ts] Argument of type '{ date: Date; comment: null; expectedCashFlow: number; hedgeRatio: number; expectedCashFlowHedge:...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Month'.
  Property '**hasAdditionalCategories**' is missing in type '{ date: Date; comment: null; expectedCashFlow: number; hedgeRatio: number; expectedCashFlowHedge:...'.

```js
const M: Month = new Month({
  date: new Date(),
  comment: null,
  expectedCashFlow: 0,
  hedgeRatio: 0,
  expectedCashFlowHedge: 0,
  categories: []
})
```

```js
export class Month {
  date: Date;
  expectedCashFlow: number;
  hedgeRatio: number;
  expectedCashFlowHedge: number;
  categories: Category[] = [];
  comment: string;
  constructor(x: Month) {
    if (x) {
      this.date = x.date;
      this.expectedCashFlow = x.expectedCashFlow;
      this.hedgeRatio = x.hedgeRatio;
      this.expectedCashFlowHedge = x.expectedCashFlowHedge;
      x.categories.forEach(
        res => this.categories.push(
          new Category(res)
        )
      );
      this.comment = x.comment;
    }
  }

  get hasAdditionalCategories(): boolean {
    return this.categories.length > 1;
  }

  get hasComment(): boolean {
    if (!this.comment) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.comment.length > 0;
    }
  }

  reset(setting: IExposureSetting): void {
    this.resetCashFlows();
    this.resetHedgeRatio(setting);
    this.resetComment();
    this.resetCategories(setting);
  }

  private resetComment(): void {
    this.comment = null;
  }

  private resetCategories(setting: IExposureSetting): void {
    this.categories = [];
    const cat: Category = new Category({
      category: setting.assumedOriginOfExposure,
      hedgeRatio: setting.defaultHedgeRatio,
      expectedCashFlow: 0,
      expectedCashFlowHedge: 0
    });
    this.categories.push(cat);
  }
  private resetCashFlows(): void {
    this.expectedCashFlow = 0;
    this.expectedCashFlowHedge = 0;
  }
  private resetHedgeRatio(setting: IExposureSetting): void {
    this.hedgeRatio = setting.defaultHedgeRatio;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to fake having classes with object initializers. Just use objects and move on. Your approach implies years of pain and suffering.

Comment: The constructor of `Month` takes something that's already a `Month`? Why? And why are you trying to override accessors with plain values?

Comment: The Month argument in the ctor is there because I'm using it to provide it with elements from a subscription. In order to have the class methods available to me. Just annotating the observable with Observable<Month> didn't get me the methods defined in the class. Actually, the Month Class is on if several in deeply nested "class of classes"... @aluan: sorry I don't get the meaning of this, I am still quite new to this

Comment: @baouss my meaning is exactly that. Since you are new to this, don't make assumptions about what it is. Especially, avoid trying to approach TypeScript as if it is some other language that you already know. Hint: classes in JavaScript are absolutely unlike classes from other mainstream languages. You cannot use the same patterns.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this.. but how am I to understand "faking"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how types work.

A `Month` means something that looks *exactly* like a `Month`, which methods and everything else.  As far as the type system is concerned, your declaration means that the ctor can call any `Month` method on its parameter.

Incidentally, that makes your class impossible to construct.

Instead, if you want to take this approach, you can move the fields to a base class or interface and make the constructor take that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I get home. Your advice with the interface that is..  I realise I have to sharpen my understanding of classes and interface

Comment: Yes that worked well. I. Now using interfaces that are implemented by the class. Arguments of type IMonth are now used.. in hindsight the error is quite logical. Thank your for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the constructor takes an instance of the class as a parameter it is imposible to construct (not without casting to `any` anyway).

There are several solutions depending on how safe you want to be and how muck you want to write:

**The anonymous interface approach**

You can define the argument's structure inline in the constructor declaration:

```
constructor(x: {date: Date;
    expectedCashFlow: number;
    hedgeRatio: number;
    expectedCashFlowHedge: number;
    categories: Category[];
    comment: string;}) { ... }
```

**`Partial<T>`**

`Partial<T>` is a type with the same structure as `T` but with all properties marked as optional. This approach has the disadvantage that you can't control which arguments are required, and since it has **the same structure as `T`** you can even specify some functions. The advantage is you don't have to specify names and types again and if you add any more fields they will appear in the constructor argument automatically

```
constructor(x: Partial<Month>) { ... }
new Month({
    comment: "", // we can specify public any field
    reset() { }  // But also methods which is not ideal
})
```

**`Pick<T, K extends keyof T>`**

Pick allows us to define a type with the property names defined by `K` (which can only contain strings that are keys for `T`) and the same types as those keys have in `T`

```
constructor(x: Pick<Month, "categories" | "date" | "hedgeRatio" | "expectedCashFlow" | "expectedCashFlowHedge" | "comment">) { ... }
```

The advantage is that you can control what properties are exposed in the constructor, all the properties are required, and that if a property gets removed or renamed, the compiler will throw an error that the property is no longer part of `T`

```
new Month({
    // we can specify all fields in the Pick
    comment: "", 
    date: new Date(),
    categories: [],
    expectedCashFlow: 0,
    hedgeRatio: 0,
    expectedCashFlowHedge: 0 
})
```

**The anonymous interface approach and use the arg as field**

Finally the last solution would be to change the structure of the class and keep all properties in a separate state field that is the arg to the constructor and use that in all methods:

```
constructor(public state: {date: Date;
    expectedCashFlow: number;
    hedgeRatio: number;
    expectedCashFlowHedge: number;
    categories: Category[];
    comment: string;}) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your very detailed answer and for providing so much background information! This is really helpful. Using an (anonymous) interface worked.

Comment: @baouss, I didn't see, it's fine it's the thought that count :)